# Mountain lion "Look up dictionary by three finger tap" does not work in some site on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, web, osx-mountain-lion

Mountain lion support look up dictionary by tapping word with three fingers. Our sites (http://www.imeigu.com,http://xueqiu.com) does not support this feature in Google Chrome, but other sites such as stackoverflow does support it. Is there any wrong configuration in our sites broke that?

Hackernews does not support this too.

Comment: Dictionary for techcrunch doesn't for chrome, but works good in safari. Would be great if someone could help fix this

Answer (score 0):

I notice these sites are in Chinese, do you have the Chinese input method installed from system prefs/language & text/input methods?

Also the Dictionary app only supports Simplified Chinese as a language type.